# Scraping .NET website I keep getting "Unable to validate data"

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I'm trying to php/curl scrape data from an .NET site (those with __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION). I monitor headers and post vars using Tamper Data so I'm pretty sure I haven't missed anything. My approach is to micmic the post back when the user click on one of the links and parse the response. But the response I'm getting is a page redirect to "Unable to validate data".

What am I missing?

Regards,

Marco

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did the asp.net site give you permission to scrape their content?

Comment: It would also be useful to include your code so far, as something like this could be the result of several bugs (not reading the values to POST back; not properly encoding them for response, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

When sending the request across, you'll need to specify the values for  `__VIEWSTATE` & `__EVENTVALIDATION` that were on the page that you're faking the user interaction from. This might mean that you have to make a standard GET request for the initial page, grab those variables, combine with your other values for your other post bits, before POSTing the whole lot back.